# Euclidean Minimum Spanning Tree Without Triangulation

Tags: graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, euclidean-distance

I was looking through some text about finding the EMST (Euclidean MST) using Delaunay triangulation technique, but also read somewhere that the EMST can be found through a sweep line algorithm. Since this would easier implementing, I would like to implement this rather than using a existing library.
Can anyone guide me/ direct me to a link to a (possibly free) paper/source that has this algorithm explained?

Comment: What did you already find with Google that didn't satisfy you?

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&q=euclidean+MST+sweepline+algorithm&oq=euclidean+MST+sweepline+algorithm) and going by the abstracts, [this](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~haizhou/publications/zhou02ipl.pdf) and [this](http://www.jucs.org/jucs_13_11/analysis_of_two_sweep) should get you started. They both use sweepline algorithms to obtain MST's

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest technique for finding Euclidean minimum spanning tree is Delaunay trinangulation, use [Bowyer-Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm) algorithm. It is very easy to implement, once you have that, you can just use something like [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm), using the distance as the edge weight.